# Nagle's algorithm on localhost

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock

Is the Nagle algorithm active on loopback connections in windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, Nagle algorithm is NOT applied to loopback TCP connections for performance reasons according to [Microsoft documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940037.aspx) (search for "loopback").